# Rattling Supply Vent

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a 4-ton HVAC system with 2 zones, with two separate thermostats for upstairs and downstairs (~1200sqft each floor). When only one zone is active (e.g upstairs) but the HVAC system is at full power (Stage 2) I hear some rattling noise from the supply vents.

I feel like the noise is because the original owners added a zoned system, but didn't account for the increased air pressure through the vents.

Can I solve this noise problem by adding a vent that has higher air flow while keeping the vent size the same? As indicated in this video?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLKm3vCii6w